# MvcMiniProfiler will not show database profiling when using code first and repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, mvc-mini-profiler

I am trying to setup database profiling with my ASP.NET MVC3 application. I have followed every blog I can find about this and the result is:

In web.config:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" />
    <add name="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" description="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" type="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProviderFactory, MvcMiniProfiler, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

In Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstrapper.Run();

    MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new SqlServerFormatter();

    var factory = new SqlConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TemplateDB"].ConnectionString);
    var profiled = new MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnectionFactory(factory);

    Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = profiled;
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal) { MiniProfiler.Start(); } 
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.Stop();
}
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;

    using (profiler.Step("call database"))
    {
        ProjectResult result = projectService.Create("slug");

        return View();
    }
}
```

I am using the repository patterns and my EF Code first lives in another project that is referenced by the MVC application.

My database class looks like:

```
public class Database : DbContext
{
    public Database(string connection) : base(connection)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(p => p.Slug).IsUnicode().IsRequired().IsVariableLength().HasMaxLength(64);
    }

    public virtual void Commit()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My database factory looks like:

```
public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory
{
    private readonly string connectionString;
    private Database database;

    public DatabaseFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNullOrEmpty(connectionString, "connectionString");

        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public Database Get()
    {
        return database ?? (database = new Database(connectionString));
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (database != null)
            database.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I run my application the profiler will not show any database profiling at all, just the regular execution time of the controller/view.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the very same issue. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889929/mvc-mini-profiler-v1-7-on-ef-4-1-code-first-project-doesnt-profile-sql[/link] The 1.7 version sets things up according to the answer @counsellorben gave. And like thomas I am still unable to get the SQL profiling to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing the Nuget MiniProfiler and MiniProfiler.EF package. Add the following in the Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    } 
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.Stop();
}
```

And finally add the below code to the head tage below JQuery of your markup.

```
@MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
```

You're set. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The notes for EF / Code First, state that your factory and other code must be run `BEFORE` any EF stuff, which leads me to suspect that installing this code in Application_Start is too late.  Try creating a pre-start class, as follows:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyApp.App_Start.AppStart_MiniProfiler), "Start")]

namespace MyApp.App_Start
{

    [INSERT using DECLARATIONS]

    public static class AppStart_MiniProfiler
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            Bootstrapper.Run();

            MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new SqlServerFormatter();

            var factory = new SqlConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TemplateDB"].ConnectionString);
            var profiled = new MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnectionFactory(factory);

            Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = profiled;
        }
    }
}
```

Create an App_Start folder in your project, and place this class in the App_Start folder.

Comment: @Thomas, what is the line `Bootstrapper.Run()` for?  Does it need to be prior to your MiniProfiler code?

Comment: It just sets up up routes, filters and some other start up tasks. I actually took it out from your code and kept it in the application start. This way AppStart_MiniProfiler.Start() runs before everything else.