# no sql profiling for Entity Framework Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, mvc-mini-profiler

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and I see that I'm not the only one with the problem (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889929/mvc-mini-profiler-v1-7-on-ef-4-1-code-first-project-doesnt-profile-sql) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757659/mvcminiprofiler-on-ef-4-1-code-first-project-doesnt-profile-sql)).

I've managed to debug for a bit, and found a solution, though I'm pretty sure that this is not the 'right' way.

The first debug session (before the dev server was enabled) showed that the *ProfiledDbConnectionFactory* and *ProfiledDbConnection* classes provide the required data, but then AFTER the connection is created, the static *Instance* property on *ProfiledDbProviderFactory* is initialized (by calling the default constructor) and apparently *CreateConnection()* is run on that instance resulting with a null reference exception (tail is null).

I've managed to solve this by running

```
ProfiledDbProviderFactory.Instance.InitProfiledDbProviderFactory(_profiler, ripInnerProvider(_conn));
```

at the end of *ProfiledDbConnection(DbConnection connection, IDbProfiler profiler)*.

This allows me to view the sql profiling, but as I wrote, I have a feeling that this isn't the correct fix.

Here's the sample [code](https://q7ehvw.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pAyoRqwkBD6g_VOHOhBrOzkIF7ymp9vII55-tsow1IjHPY_NYpdsGefRlTOka_1Tn_YvU1aW3M-wyi7-l5Au2XQ/Prof.zip?download&psid=1) I used.
Not sure if there is something wrong with my environment, or my code, as I have a feeling that this should work out of the box. Any comments/suggestions?
Sam?

Comment: Could you please post more of your code and exactly what the problem is you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved in version 1.9.1 of MiniProfiler.EF

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with using ProfiledDbConnectionFactory entity framework is designed to support ignorance i generally just use the debugger tools and create a breakpoint to view my generated sql statements as the code first framework provides the sql statement readily there

i would stick to using profiled connections the way you described in your unit testing as opposed to using it in production code as the profiling may be a performance hit you way also want to consider using the sql profiler included in sql server and there is also an sql profiler available as a visual studio extension however i am not sure if it supports code first as of yet

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that's not what I was talking about - I'm not looking for a different profiler - I'm looking for a way to make the mvc mini profiler work with my code